# Diagram symbol for an inductance with a neodymium magnet as a core

Tags: inductance, diagram, symbol, core

I want to know if there is such a symbol (i.e. an electrical diagram symbol for an inductance with a magnet as a core).  If such is the case how is it specified the orientation of the poles of the magnet? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't a coil with a magnet inside it called a motor...? Or a Moving Coil Panel Meter...?

Comment: then you are saying guitar pickups are a motor (or a moving coil panel meter).

Comment: No, a guitar pickup is a guitar pickup. I'd have thought that was obvious. The point I am making is that you put the device in the schematic, not what it is made of.

Comment: Often the datasheet will have some form of symbol on it you can use as a basis for your own symbol. What does the datasheet of your mystery component say?

Comment: there is no datasheet because its a "custom" (hand-made) coil. We used two of them and each one had a magnet. There is no special need to say in the diagram what was the magnet made of, but yes its orientation. I got around the problem putting a red and blue bar beside the inductances. Thanks

Comment: That's one way of doing it but beware of using colour like that in a schematic. Print it out on a mono laser printer and which way is which? Better would be to put an arrow and N to indicate north inside the bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schematics are Logic diagrams and do not indicate the material or all specifications just par numbers .  If you wish to convey this information, be creative. or add to the notes.

[image: schematic]
[image]

[image]

https://conceptdraw.com/a1511c3/preview

[image]
In any case, you may buy or find library files above for symbols or make your own.